# Cannot dynamically create select with its options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to dynamically create a div with a select input inside but it turns out that there is an empty div with noting.

As you can see, $eduRow is a div that used as a container. Trying to solve it in many ways but still not working(always came up with an empty div).

I have a clicking button that will dynamically create these select stuff after click.

Here is the function that's written inside document ready function.

```
$("#addMoreEdu").on('click', function() {

  var $eduRow = $("#edu-row");


  var select = $('<select />', {
    'class': 'selectoption'
  });


  $(select).append($('<option value="" disabled selected>Degree option</option>'));
  $(select).append($('<option value="1">High School</option>'))
  $(select).append($('<option value="2">College</option>'))
  $(select).append($('<option value="3">Bachelors degree</option>'))

  var div = $('<div />', {
    'class': 'input-field col s12 m4 l4'
  });

  $(div).append(select)

  $eduRow.append(div);

  $eduRow.append('<div class="input-field col s12 m4 l8"><span class="fieldLabel"> Institutes Name</span><input placeholder="Institutes Name" id="IntsName" type="text" /></div>');
});
```

Another weird thing is that the second append works fine. I think there must be some problem with select :\ 
Any ideas?

NOTE: I have my code up here[codepen](http://codepen.io/bhbo/pen/YWLBao) if you can take a look at Educational Background section.

Comment: `disabledselected`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ran this code in a blank project and it works. The only change I made was to wrap your code in a `$(document).ready(function () { YOUR CODE HERE });` construct. I would suggest you may have another issue either with your selector, or with your script inclusion for jQuery.

try putting a `debugger;` line in and running with the debug tools going (F12)

Comment: I have update and add the whole code of the function.

Comment: you will still need the document ready construct.  See this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/linskin/d8fdpqsd/1/

Comment: I have already put that function into the document ready  but it still not working.

Comment: did you check out the fiddle?  It's working in there and the code is the same as yours (but I did use $("#addMoreEdu").on('click', function() { rather than the click bind.

Comment: It seems to be working fine on fiddle but I have no idea why it is not in my code becauseI have your code copy and paste. Is it possible if something wrong with css or js framework?

Comment: strip out all the code apart from the $(document).ready(function(){}); body, and insert an alert('hi'); in the function body.  If you get your alert then you know jQuery is all running OK. Then do the same with the click handler body, strip out everything and replace it with a simple alert. try the click, see the alert, then that is all ok. from there it's just a case of figuring out what;s wrong in the code you've stripped out.

Comment: I think other thing working ok. I have the whole code up here http://codepen.io/bhbo/pen/YWLBao please take a look at Educational Background section and thank you for you time.

Comment: Your problem was being caused by the styling.  You have a specific call to style all of your selects.  Once you have added the new select item you need to make this call again:

so after :
`$eduRow.append(div);`
add :
`$('select').material_select();`

Comment: Problem solved! I have to be more careful next time. Thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 1):

So you have to wait for document to load and then define your elements as in HTML with opening and closing tag, and specify attributes in opening tag :

I suppose you have this html :

```
<div id="edu-row">

</div>
```

JavaScript should like this :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    var $eduRow = $("#edu-row");
    var select = $('<select class="selectoption"><select />');
    //you can append html without $() 
    $(select).append('<option value="" disabled selected>Degree option</option>');
    $(select).append('<option value="1">High School</option>')
    $(select).append('<option value="2">College</option>')
    $(select).append('<option value="3">Bachelors degree</option>')

    var div = $('<div class="input-field col s12 m4 l4"></div >');
    $(div).append(select)

    $eduRow.append(div);
})
```

Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/m0786yq4/

Comment: I have update and add the whole code of the function.

Comment: My laptop is dead and its late here (UK) so I'll take a look in the a.m. for you.

Answer (score 0):

This will append the div & drop down to the end of the body, you can use any other tag to control where the html will be added.

```
$('body').append('<div id="maindiv"></div>');
$('#maindiv').append('<select id="ddww" class="selectoption"></select>');
$('#ddww').append('<option value="" selected>Degree option</option>');
//all other options
```